# How to enumerate Stream results

Tags: dart, stream

I have a Stream, that yields Strings like this:

```
'apple'
'orange'
'banana'
```

When I listen to the Stream, I want to assign numbers to the results from 1 to n (Stream lenght) in the order they were yielded like this:

```
1: 'apple'
2: 'orange'
3: 'banana'
```

What is the best way to do that?

---

As there is no `enumerate()` function like in Python, my attempts so far are pretty bad:
inside Stream definition

```
int n = 0
await for (var nextString in originStream) {
  ++n;
  yield [n, nextString];
}
```

when stream is called

```
myStream.transform(enumerateFunc)

List enumerateFunc(String myStr){
  return [n, myStr];
}
```

I got a suggestion to create a class for this. But I don't want to create a class for simply assing numbers to Stream events in the order they happenned.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should really not use `List` as a tuple since you are loosing the type information. Instead, create a class for your purpose and return objects from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @julemand101 suggested, a pretty viable option is to create a class for this purpose and yield the class instead of List:

```
Stream<String> fruits() async* {
  int n = 1;
  await for (final String fruit in fruitChannel) {
    yield Enumerated(n, fruit);
    n++;
  }
}
```